# Android Convert Currency TextView Back To Double

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I have a TextView called cardBalance

```
cardBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCardBalance);
```

And I set the text for cardBalance like so

```
double amount = 109.00;
NumberFormat baseFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String moneyString = baseFormat.format(amount)
cardBalance.setText(moneyString);
```

This works fine and displays with the $ symbol as desired, my struggle now is how do I get this the value and covert it back to double?

I tried the following without success

```
double bal = Double.parseDouble(cardBalance.getText().toString());
```

How can I get the double value back without the $ symbol

Comment: Have you tried without the toString() method in the end? getText() should be sufficient if I remember correctly?

Comment: Yes, the Double.parseDouble() method requires a String to be passed in, so if I try without the toString() I it will not compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `NumberFormat` object can be used for parsing as well as formatting.

Documentation for [`NumberFormat.parse()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

> Parses a Number from the specified string using the rules of this
>   number format.

So, just use `baseFormat.parse(cardBalance.getText().toString())).doubleValue();`

Comment: Thank you, I tried and I am getting ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.land.Double.

Comment: @ValOkafor Did you put `.doubleValue()` as in the snippet above?